# How to refresh/update Ag-Grid from CellRenderer and HeadRenderers

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

I need to update/refresh Ag-Grid table from HeadRenderer and CellRenderer.
For instance i have a button in CellRenderer and when this button is pressed.
The table is refreshed.

```
const HeaderRenderer = (values) => {
        return (
     <>
      <Button
        onClick={ (e) =>
         {
           //code which redraws Ag-Grid tables
          }
        }
      />
    </>
   );
}
```

Although i cannot find any documentation how to do it from CellRenderers.
Theoretically i should use `gridApi.refreshCells` but when i use it in CellRenderer and HeadRenderer those api are unfefined.
Even it is defined in `onGridReady`.
I was thinking to update it with `values` params.
I think it has to be possible but i didn't find any functions for that?
[image]
Does anyone knows is it possible to do with `values` params from `CellRenderer` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the grid api from the cell renderer params.

Try:

```
const HeaderRenderer = (values) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={(e) => {
          values.api.refreshCells();
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but unfortunately it doesnt work

Comment: Maybe try values.api.redrawRows(). Does that work? Why are you refreshing?

Comment: Yes, i tried that also. Unfortunatelly it didn't work. Table just flashed for a second, but it still shows old unupdated data. And cell renderers as well show previous values like they wasn't even called. I need to refresh table because i have a column with cell renderers each holds button. And when HeadeRenderer is clicked the buttons in CellRednerers should change its color.